# How to upgrade package to latest version using yarn?

Tags: javascript, eslint, yarnpkg

I would like to upgrade `eslint` package to latest version.

`yarn upgrade eslint --latest` do nothing.

How can I update to latest version via yarn?

Comment: I do mostly `yarn add eslint@latest`

Answer (score 3):

Recipe of my recent technique.

Some time ago command below started failing to work

> yarn upgrade somePackage -- latest

It's started to has side effects like updating other packages as babel, typescript etc. I don't see any comments about this behavior in official [documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade/). Going to codebase of yarn is a bit overhead in order to solve so "basic" task

Currently in order to update single package i use

> yarn add somePackage

In order to update to latest i use

> yarn add somePackage@latest

So, in your case i recommend you to try

> yarn add eslint@latest

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )